# Analyzing non-Visual Studio, Unity C# code with MSBuild/SonarQube via Jenkins

Tags: unity-game-engine, jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarqube-msbuild-runner

I inherited the responsibility for a SonarQube Linux server which was running version 5.1 and analyzing dozens of Unity C# projects. After upgrading it to SQ 6.1 I discovered that support for analyzing C# projects on non-Windows systems was dropped in version 5.5, so I downgraded it to version 5.4 for the present time.

I have subsequently set up a Windows system as a Jenkins node and SonarQube server. However, the projects I am hoping to evaluate with SonarQube are (mostly) developed on and (always) built on macOS in Unity and therefore lack MSbuild solution files. Is it at all possible for me to use SonarQube within these constraints, short of adding Visual Studio-specific code to the projects? Is there some kind of dummy solution file that I could add to the projects that would allow them to be analyzed without the expectation of a working binary being produced (along the lines of parsing/tokenizing without compiling/linking)? Thanks.

Comment: What is the compiler you are using for this project? Our C# analyzer rely on Roslyn. Is there an official support of Roslyn on MaxOSX?

Comment: Unity is a compiler. I am aware of Roslyn and would like to use it to write some of our own coding checks. I have since learned that Unity does create solution files, even on macOS, and so I will be able to use Jenkins to open the projects in Unity in order to create the solution files prior to launching the analysis in SonarQube. When I have this all working, I will post an answer for posterity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the procedure I have developed for analyzing Unity projects in SonarQube via Jenkins.

1. A user-facing Jenkins job with the following settings and options, among others specific to my environment.

   1. **General—This project is parameterized**

      1. **String parameter** `PROJECTKEY`
      2. **String parameter** `PROJECTNAME`
      3. **String parameter** `PROJECTVERSION`
   2. **General—Restrict where this project can be run** set to the Jenkins build node name you used for your SonarQube server.
   3. **Source Code Management**

      1. **Repository URL** set to the repository you want to analyze.
      2. **Branches to build** set to the main branch, i.e. `refs/heads/master`.
      3. **Additional Behaviors—Recursively update submodules** checked as appropriate for your repository.
   4. **Build Triggers**

      1. **Poll SCM** checked, but no schedule specified.
   5. **Build Environment**

      1. **Run buildstep before SCM runs—Inject environment variables** set to `HOME=C:\Users\Jenkins` (or as appropriate for your system). This environment variable makes it possible for git to find the correct ssh credentials to use with the Git server. You'll need to put your git private key in `%HOME%\.ssh`; that is documented elsewhere and left as an exercise to the reader.
      2. **Use build environment from another project—Template Project** pointing to a second Jenkins job. Mine is called *SonarQube_Scanner* (see below).
   6. **Build**

      1. **Use builders from another project—Template Project** pointing to the same Jenkins job `SonarQube_Scanner`.
   7. **Post-build Actions**

      1. **Archive the artifacts—Files to archive** set to `log.zip`.
2. A non-user-facing Jenkins job (*SonarQube_Scanner*) with the following settings and options.

   1. **General—Disable this project** checked.
   2. **General—Restrict where this project can be run** checked and set to your SonarQube server.
   3. **Source Code Management** set to None.
   4. **Build Environment—Inject environment variables to the build process** checked.

      1. **Properties Content** contains

         ```
         `LANG=en_US.UTF-8`
         ```
   5. **Build**

      1. **Execute Windows batch command** contains

         ```
         set FILENAME=%WORKSPACE%\client\Assets\Editor\SQMenuItems.cs
         REM Yes, this syntax works and is sooo much more readable
          > %FILENAME% ECHO using UnityEditor;
         >> %FILENAME% ECHO public static class SQMenuItems {
         >> %FILENAME% ECHO   static void AssetsOpenCSharpProject() {
         >> %FILENAME% ECHO #if UNITY_5
         >> %FILENAME% ECHO     EditorApplication.ExecuteMenuItem("Assets/Open C# Project");
         >> %FILENAME% ECHO #else
         >> %FILENAME% ECHO     EditorApplication.ExecuteMenuItem("Assets/Sync MonoDevelop Project");
         >> %FILENAME% ECHO #endif
         >> %FILENAME% ECHO     EditorApplication.Exit(0);
         >> %FILENAME% ECHO   }
         >> %FILENAME% ECHO }
         "C:\Program Files\Unity_5.5.2\Editor\Unity.exe" -quit -batchmode -nographics -logFile "%WORKSPACE%\log.txt" -buildTarget android -projectPath %WORKSPACE%\client -executeMethod SQMenuItems.AssetsOpenCSharpProject
         "C:\Program Files\7-zip\7z.exe" -tzip a log.zip log.txt
         ```

         - SQMenuItems.cs is what triggers Unity to create the `.sln` and `.*proj` files that MSBuild needs. The `.sln` and `.*proj` files are typically in the `.gitignore` file and therefore not in the repository.
      2. **SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild - Begin Analysis**

         1. **SonarQube Installation** set to the Jenkins build node name you used for your SonarQube server.
         2. **Project key** set to `${PROJECTKEY}`.
         3. **Project name** set to `${PROJECTNAME}`.
         4. **Project version** set to `${PROJECTVERSION}`.
         5. **Additional arguments**

            `/d:sonar.exclusions=**\\SQMenuItems.cs`
      3. **Execute Windows batch command**

         ```
         "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" /maxcpucount /nr:false /nologo /target:rebuild /verbosity:quiet client\client.sln
         ```

         - You may need to change `client\client.sln` above to match your environment. I haven't yet tried replacing that with an environment variable defined in the user-facing Jenkins job.
      4. **SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild - End Analysis**
3. **DONE**
4. **GOTCHAS**

   1. If the job fails because Unity fails because it can't find the projectPath, it may have forgotten its license key. Remote desktop to your SonarQube server and launch the Unity GUI. If it pops up asking for your license key, re-enter the key, then quit. Subsequent jobs should succeed.
   2. Things that make it **very difficult** to pass information to SonarQube in a dynamic way.

      1. Windows environment variables defined in 2.5.1 “Execute Windows batch command” are not preserved through to 2.5.2 “SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild - Begin Analysis”.
      2. The `SonarQube.Analysis.xml` file specifically prohibits assigning the properties `sonar.projectName`, `sonar.projectKey`, and `sonar.projectVersion`.
5. I've probably overlooked something; please don't hesitate to inquire.